# Python opencv issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, opencv, computer-vision

I am learning OpenCV and I've run into some problems.

My code:

```
import cv2 as cv


img = cv.imread("testImage.png")
if img is None:
    print("Check image path")

cv.imshow("image window", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem is that the code from the line: `cv.imshow("image window", img)` does not run, and the image is not shown.
I do not get any errors or warnings from the code.

I have tried that in multiple projects, different Python versions (Python 3.8 is the current version I tried).

I've also tried different OpenCV versions, but with no luck.

Though before I re-installed my mac, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Check if your program is reading the image correctly first, if not, check the path. Then try to plot it with Matplotlib. Your code above works fine for me in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code runs on my machine: `python 3.6.6` `openCV 3.3.1` on Windows.
There are a few things you can try:

1. **check your path**- you can get your current path running these 2 lines in your console:

> ```
> import os
> os.getcwd()
> ```

2. **check that the image loads successfully** - maybe the name is not right. maybe it's a jpg image and not png image. double check that.
3. Attach the specific error that shows in the console and we will try to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you pointed me in the right direction. The problem wasn't with Python but actually my mistake. I just realized that as I am using a beta of Big Sur, there could be already Python3 pre-installed, which wasn't in earlier versions, if I remember well. So I automatically installed a new Python3 which may cause some corruption, maybe? After uninstalling all versions of Python and installing a new one ( 3.8 ), everything works as expected.

TL;DR - Uninstalling all versions of Python, and installing a new one fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code (with my image of course) and it worked fine. I have 2 suggestions, why yours is not working.
The first may be the same problem that i have where you have to put the exact path name like this for it to work:

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread("/Users/syedrishad/Downloads/Lambo.jpg")
if img is None:
    print("Check image path")

cv.imshow("image window", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Or my second suggestion is that the image name is not right. A slight misspelling or a change from a jpeg to a jpg could throw off your whole program.
Could you also write what do you use(for example pycharm, IDLE, VScode) and try to find the exact error?